# Converte dados do tipo time dentro de array para int ou float. Erro: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'numpy.str_'

Tags: django, lista, datetime, time

Estou tentando converter dados dentro de uma list[array], que possui dados do tipo time(str)... segue o codigo abaixo:

def ProdGrafico(request):
## Dados Media Duracao do Forno

```
mediaForno = Relatorioresumido.objects.all()
divideForno = len(mediaForno)
listMediaForno = []

for x in range(int(divideForno)):
    y = mediaForno[x].duracaoforno
    listMediaForno.append(y)


listMediaForno = numpy.array(listMediaForno)
print(listMediaForno)
try:
    mediaForno = (sum(listMediaForno) / len(listMediaForno))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    mediaForno = 0
```

O erro é gerado ao chegar no Try:

mediaForno = (sum(listMediaForno) / len(listMediaForno))

Nome do Erro: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'numpy.str_'

Answer (score -2):

Se você puder adicionar o resultado do print(listaMediaForno), mas provavelmente o atributo duracaoforno deve estar em string (por exemplo '10' em vez de 10), então o erro está ocorrendo pois está tentando somar um array de strings(numpy.str_). Se estiver algo assim:

```
>>> print(listMediaForno)
['10', '20', '30']
```

Uma solução seria trocar no modelo, o tipo do duracaoforno.

Alternativamente, na linha da criação do array pode fazer essa conversão:

```
listMediaForno = numpy.array(listMediaForno).astype(float)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica... Eu consegui resolver esse problema, os dados  estavam vindo do banco de dados nesse formato "00:00:50", não tinha como converte para inteiro, mas esse código resolveu esse meu probema,

Comment: segue o código:

Answer (score -2):

@login_required()
def ProdGrafico(request):

```
## Dados Media Duracao do Forno
mediaForno = Relatorioresumido.objects.all()
divideForno = len(mediaForno)
listMediaForno = []
for x in range(int(divideForno)):
    y = mediaForno[x].duracaoforno
    y = datetime.strptime(y, '%H:%M:%S')
    y = y.strftime("%M.%S")
    y = float(y)
    listMediaForno.append(y)
try:
    mediaForno = round((sum(listMediaForno) / len(listMediaForno)), 2)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    mediaForno = 0
```